# Make vue router stay on same page if condition is not met

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Im working on a vue app and I navigate through pages with vue router from the different page views, I want to set up vue router in a way where it would push a route if there is no error and stay on the same view/route if there is one. I have the following code that succeeds but I'm unsure if that is the best way to do it, and afraid it may cause bugs:

```
login() {
  this.$store
    .dispatch("method", {})
    .then(() => {
      if (!this.error) {
        this.$router.push({ name: "nextPage" });
      } else {
        this.$router.push({ name: "samePage" });
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can stay on the same page by doing nothing

Comment: As @EstusFlask said: remove your else section or do resetting state stuff there.